# Loading SystemJS in html ends up with error in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, systemjs

I'm using PhantomJS to setup CI for jasmine tests. I'm facing the problem with including SystemJS in my html page. I removed everything from it, just left javascript and still facing the same error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: System

Here is the example of html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js">   </script>
        <script>
            System.config({
                baseURL: './lib'

            });
      </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I ran it in console like that: phantomjs test.js http://localhost:8080.

test.js contains following code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(system.args[1], function(status)
{
    phantom.exit(0);
});
```

It looks like it doesn't see system.src.js. I tried to put there absolute path - but still the same error. Also tried with page.injectJs - no good either.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I'm using PhantomJS 2, I receive no other error, only that one I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found an answer and I want to share it, maybe someone will find it useful. I logged page.outerHTML and saw that instead of script with system.src.js I've got additional script with  system-polyfills.js. It looked like that:

```
<script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/lib/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js">
```

So I've just added missing system-polyfills.js to the following folder and it fixed the error. Although I still have no idea where it came from.